# call ajax function to reset the flag in database

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have to call the ajax function to reset the flag in database on the browser close event.

I am doing so for the prevent the multiple log in for that I have set the flag on log in event but I have to reset it on browser close event so I have to do it by ajax function but I am new to to so please guide me to call ajax function.

I have refereed the [que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591590/how-to-prevent-user-to-login-from-multiple-location-or-from-different-browser-in/18591653?noredirect=1#comment28035951_18591653)

Comment: How are you exposing your functions? If you want to make an AJAX call, you need to call a webmethod or a controller action from web api AFAIK.

Comment: I generally find this useful for people new to this site: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can make an ajax request to your server to reset database flag.

```
$.ajax({
        url: your url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            Flag: value
        },
        error: function () { alert("Unexpected Error"); },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: in which function i have to write above code

if i write it in 
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
};

then this will be also get called when it redirect to another page

Comment: In which language, you are building your application? And you have to write this function inside your browser close event.

Comment: am building it in ASP.NET

Comment: i have same problem as him

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792741/how-to-call-window-close-function-only-for-tab-or-browser-closing